# What does it mean if a struct pointer has a value of 0xfbad2488

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm writing a program that uses the following structures to store information:

```
/* Structure used to hold a graph vertex information. */
typedef struct graph_vertex
{
    int identifier;
    struct graph_vertex *next_vertex_p;
    struct graph_edge *edge_list_p;
    boolean_t visited;
} graph_vertex_t;

/* Structure used to hold a graph edge information. */
typedef struct graph_edge
{
    struct graph_vertex *adjac_vertex_p;
    struct graph_edge *next_edge_p;
} graph_edge_t;
```

Basically, the first structure is used to store a list of vertices while the second is used by the first to store the connections(edges). Now I'm trying to look through the list of edges for a certain vertex I found and do an operation. I use the following code for this:

```
/* Find the right vertex to explore*/
for (curr_graph = start;
     curr_graph != NULL && curr_graph->identifier != list[0];
     curr_graph = curr_graph->next_vertex_p);
    
/* Explore all it's edges for new vertices. */
for (curr_edge_list = curr_graph->edge_list_p;
     curr_edge_list != NULL;
     curr_edge_list = curr_edge_list->next_edge_p)
{
    printf("ID: %d ,", curr_edge_list->adjac_vertex_p->identifier);
    /*do more stuff...*/
```

Currently I'm getting a segmentation fault on the line with the printf which I checked using gdb. I also checked the values of `curr_edge_list` , `curr_edge_list->adjac_vertex_p` and `curr_edge_list->adjac_vertex_p->identifier` :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554c9f in start_visit_graph_bf (start=0x7fffffffdee0, 
    starting_identifier=1) at explore_graph.c:170
170                 printf("ID: %d ,", curr_edge_list->adjac_vertex_p->identifier);
(gdb) print curr_edge_list
$1 = (graph_edge_t *) 0x5555557574a0
(gdb) print curr_edge_list->adjac_vertex_p
$2 = (struct graph_vertex *) 0xfbad2488
(gdb) print curr_edge_list->adjac_vertex_p->identifier
Cannot access memory at address 0xfbad2488
(gdb)
```

My first instinct was that the value `0xfbad2488` was a code used to describe NULL, so I checked that `curr_edge_list->adjac_vertex_p` wasn't equal to NULL before the printf statement. This was not the case. Therefor my question is: What is the value 0xfbad2488 and what does it mean if a variable has that value? Also which operations cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: My guess is that curr_edge_list->adjac_vertex_p is not initialized and you are getting UB trying to access it.

Comment: My guess is the same thing here, although I don't understand where that would be coming from. As far as I can tell I'm only creating graph_edge_t types in one place and there I am initializing adjac_vertex_p

Comment: I did a web search for 0xfbad2488 . It's a commonly used set of flags in a stdio FILE structure. Look for uninitialized variables and also out-of-bounds array accesses in variables declared adjacent to FILE * variables. Running [valgrind](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) or compiling with [Address Sanitizer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) may help.

Answer (score 0):

> My first instinct was that the value 0xfbad2488 was a code used to describe NULL

No, `NULL` will look like this in GDB:

```
(gdb) print curr_edge_list->adjac_vertex_p
$2 = (struct graph_vertex *) 0x0
```

What you want to do is figure out which location is being overwritten (`print &curr_edge_list->adjac_vertex_p`), and set a watchpoint on it:

```
(gdb) watch -l curr_edge_list->adjac_vertex_p
```

Then run your program again. If your program is deterministic (doesn't use threads), you should see the location acquire initial value (should look similar to your other pointers, e.g. `0x55555575...`, and then you should see it being overwritten with `0xfbad2488`. That is *exactly* the point where the bug is (where your data is getting corrupted).